# I want to swipe 3 view Pager at the same time automatically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to swipe three ViewPager on the same activity automatically, each viewPager is inside a fragment and each viewPager has to loop 5 images, when my timer starts to swipe the first viewPager it works fine, but when I start the second one, my app crashes and tells that the children already has a parent.

So my question is how can I swipe 3 viewPager automatically at the same time? I've tried putting the viewPager without fragment and starting to swipe them but the app crashes with the same error, and when I swipe them manually it also crashes.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5161)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4991)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1485)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4931)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4904)
    at appName.Data.MiddleAdapter.instantiateItem(MiddleAdapter.java:33)


// Line that crashes the app
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position)
    ImageView image = images.get(position);
    container.addView(image);
    return image;
```

The other 3 view pagers have the exact line, when only one is activated it works fine.

Comment: override destroyitem method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ViewPager removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329499/viewpager-removeview-on-the-childs-parent-first)

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your custom adapter

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
((ViewPager) container).removeView(itemView); }
```

Comment: I already overode onDestroyItem but the app still crashes. I've goy 3 adapters one for each ViewPager.
    public Object instantiateItem(NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView image = images.get(position);
        container.addView(image);
        return image;
    }


    public boolean isViewFromObject(NonNull View view, NonNull Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }

    Override
    public void destroyItem(NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }